# Control points in IAdjustXForm for georeferencing of raster (ArcObjects)

Tags: raster, arcobjects, georeferencing, arcgis-engine

I am trying to create a georeferencing tool using ArcObjects in VB.Net. Though only a little text is available on this topic in forums as well as from ESRI; I found an [esri article](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/NET/8b5c071a-fd25-4b7f-9f47-2852bdf54546.htm) that states the use of IAdjustXForm for performing the desired transformations on input raster map and [this article](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/java/d1a6461d-47da-467f-92d0-a0cb04f0f111.htm) to create the AdjustXForm using control points.

I have built the interface to place a selected raster file as IRasterLayer on Map Control without any projection. After loading, user can mark the corners of the map image (un-referenced) on map control (by mouse click) and input the correct lat/lon for those points.

```vb
Dim sourcePC As IPointCollection = New Multipoint
sourcePC.AddPoint(TopLeftPoint)
sourcePC.AddPoint(BottomRightPoint)
```

I have tried building two **IPointCollection** initialized as a **MultiPoint** object by adding the user selected points (from mouse clicks) as source points (**IPoint**) and input coordinates (from text blocks) as target points (**IPoint**).

But it throws an exception - **Exception from HRESULT: 0x80041034**

So, now question is - I am not sure that control points for IAdjustXForm are meant to be the ones I have selected, or if yes, Are the source points pixel locations in image space or geographic coordinates after placing the raster on map?